# iOS 4.3: Difficulty attaching graphic to an Image View

Tags: objective-c, xcode4, uiimage, viewdidload, ios4

I am a relative novice who is teaching himself Objective-C on Xcode to develop some simple iPhone game apps. I have done some reading on this but fear I'm missing something basic and obvious.

I made a simple "Hello, World" and, based on opinions in various forums, I decided to do a Tic Tac Toe. I found a nice video and built a version based on that, which ran fine. However, my own interpretation is already running into trouble.

I'm using Xcode 4.0.2 on Snow Leopard. I chose a View-Based Application template and pulled a large image view onto the layout to hold a PNG called board. I put nine small image views on the large one to hold individual cells for X and O (and created some PNGs for the images). I just attached board.png to the big image view through IB so that works fine.

Next I tried to associate cell 1 with x.png by assigning it to a variable called ximg. This is all set up in the view controller's viewDidLoad method like so -- "ximg = [UIImage imageNamed:@"x.png"];". I then used the code "cell1.image = ximg;" -- also in viewDidLoad. X appeared on the board when I built and ran.

My next step was cell 2. I wanted to use a variable in a custom method this time, so I could change it in the future. I declared a method "- (void)setcell2" (bad camelCase, I know). I put the following method into my view controller implementation file:

`-(void)setcell2 {`

```
cell2.image = ximg;
```

}

I also added the following message to viewDidLoad --  "[self setcell2];"

As you'd guess, I was figuring that when the app loaded, viewDidLoad would send that message to setcell2, which would attach another X in the second box, but this didn't happen.

If someone could give me some idea of what I'm overlooking, I'd be gratified. Example code is appreciated but I can figure that out with time. This is not homework. Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely you haven't set your cell up properly in Interface Builder. Make sure you have connected the property to the outlet.

Comment: Thank you. However, it seemed that if ximg was nil, it wouldn't show up in cell1 either. Is that the case?

Comment: Thanks so much, FreeAsInBeer, that was it, exactly.I went to the XIB and selected cell2. I right-clicked and dragged from File's Owner to the UIImageView and, when I released, I got a popup to select my cell2 outlet. When I built and ran, Xs showed in cells 1 and 2, as expected. You've been a great help.

Comment: @chordam7: Glad to be of assistance. When I began working in Objective-C, I found these same kind of issues to have simple solutions, but there are several steps and easy to mess up. Best of luck!